# Magicavoxel export to Unity offcenter

Tags: unity, importing, magicavoxel

I am trying to export an object from Magicavoxel to Unity. I have exported it as an `obj` file and dragged it into the scene, but it is completely off centered compared to other objects.

For example, in the image below you can see the object I imported to the top left and a simple box in the middle. Both objects have a `transform.position` of 0,0,0. However, you can clearly see that the objects don't overlap. Is there a way to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this issue myself.

First, I pressed `tab` to switch to the `World editor`. In there, I moved the object down and into the negative axis so it would line up perfectly. The 2 objects are now within each other for me.